# The slopes angles are not getting calculated correctly from given two points on opencv generated image (without numpy)

Tags: python, opencv

The slopes of the lines are wrongly being calculated.Please find the below image for your reference.
Basically, I am trying to understand if the line is right or left of the center point.

I have tried swapping the parameters, also tried adding 180,90 -360,-180 degrees from the slope. On adding 45 or -45 others slopes are getting messed up (without 
adding 45/-45 also, still it is not close to accurate value).

[image: lines slope]

```
def dist(xc,yc,lin_arr):

    distance =math.sqrt( ((xc -lin_arr[0])**2)+((yc -lin_arr[1])**2) )

    m=0
    m=int((yc-lin_arr[1])/(xc-lin_arr[0]) )
    slope=math.degrees(math.atan(m))+45
    print("distance",distance,xc,yc,lin_arr,"slope:",(slope))

    return distance,(slope)
```

The variables, xc & yc are the x and y coordinates of the center point or point 1. lin_arr is the value of the point in array format of point 2().

While lin_arr is itself derived from the below line of code:

```
ret,thresh = cv2.threshold(img,max_lin ,255,0)
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
for i in range(0,len(contours)):
            cnt = contours[i]
            rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
            box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
            listy = []
            for row in range(4):
                inner_list = []
                for col in range(2):
                    inner_list.append(box[row][col])

                listy.append(inner_list)

            print("tjos/n",listy)

            for i in range(4):
                s,slope= dist(xc,(2*yc),listy[i])
                im=cv2.line(img, tuple((xc,(2*yc))), tuple(listy[i]), (0,255,0), 2, cv2.LINE_AA, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are ignoring the fact that y is 0 on the upper part. Therefore, the slope that would be:

```
m = (y2-y1) / (x2-x1)
```

Now, should be:

```
m = ((img_height-y2)-(img_height-y1) / (x2 -x1)
```

And you can re-write that as:

```
m = (img_height - y2 - img_height + y1) / (x2 -x1)
m = (y1-y2) / (x2 -x1)  # -y2+y1 == y1-y2
```

Then:

```
slope = math.degrees(math.atan(m))
```

Of course, you still have to handle edge-cases.

Comment: So what i did for my project(could be wrong) , i found the center points first . then calculated the points coordinates and simply  deduced if the point coordinates in positive or negative  referenced from the center. Simple approach.  But i also agree your point is valid already, and should have worked, but for me it didn't. :/

Comment: @ShariqAzim I did not understand why it did not work. Did you get wrong results?

Comment: i dont know , but yes i was getting absolutely wrong results.

Comment: @ShariqAzim I'm sorry, but other than the edge cases (which I mentioned in the answer), this code should provide you the correct results. I really look forward to having some examples so that I can fix, if there is anything to be fixed. Can you at least answer you own question with your solution so that I can compare?